# Why does Update Manager show software not previously installed?

Tags: apt, updates, update-manager

Update Manager is showing package `tomcat8` in the list of updates. I don't have Tomcat installed, nor have I ever, why is it appearing in the *update* list?

This is a bit worrying, as it means I have probably mistakenly installed other packages assuming that they were just updates.

Comment: @Rinzwind 1. good handle - 2. `adduser`!? That's a surprise, why on earth would a command-line utility feel the need to use a servlet container!? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the `tomcat8` package is installed in your system. Not necessarily with Tomcat application.

It can be a dependency of some other package.

You can check it by

```
apt-cache rdepends tomcat8
```